# How to authenticate the HTML static files under GeoServer installation

Tags: geoserver, authentication, files, static

I'm using GeoServer 2.22.2. and now I can access the static files under data_dir/www/.for example: http://publicip:8080/geoserver/www/index.html.but I don't want all those files exposed to the role unauthenticated.

Does anyone know how to apply security policies to this directory and block ROLE_ANONYMOUS request to the static files in the data_dir/www/?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but try the following:

- Go To the authentication menu item
- Create a new filter chain, similar to the "default" one, but remove anonymous access and set the path for it to "/www/**"
- Save it, and then move it so that it occurs before the default chain

At this point anonymous access to anything under "www" should be disallowed.

Comment: i have just tried as your suggestion,it's still not working. (the data access rule is bundled with workplace by default,thus i added a workplace named www with url http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www).maybe the workplace is just for layers&stores, the statics files is not what it serves